# Imprimir fecha con campo tipo Date sin ceros

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, date, eloquent

Tengo en mi base de datos varios campos donde guardo las fechas, estos campos son tipo DATE, tengo entendido que los campos tipo date solo guardar la fecha osea AÑO-MES-DIA

Pero mi problema es que al imprimirlo, me muestra las horas de este forma 2019-02-06 00:00:00.0

Como puedo hacer para que me imprima solo la fecha guardada AÑO-MES-DIA de forma natural desde la base de datos.

Cuando imprimo con un dd()

```
dd($empleados[6]->tareas[0]->fecha_termino);
```

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que imprime en pantalla
Cuando imprimo con un echo

```
 echo $empleados[6]->tareas[0]->fecha_termino ;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que no se confundan, lo que pasa es que la fecha se me imprime de esta forma 2019-02-06 00:00:00. Pero lo que necesito es que se me imprima a si 2019-02-06

Necesito hacer esto tanto como para PHP como para javascript.

Comment: ¿Pero es para mostrarlo en pantalla? Es extraño que quieras formatear una fecha usando `dd` ¿no?

Comment: si para mostrarlo en pantalla, no tratode formatearla, con el dd imprimo lo que hay en la variable que me muestra los daros en ese campo. Cuando no renderizo con expresiones en la vista es lo mismo

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario... O sea, `dd` es para hacer debug, lo que no entiendo es por qué quieres aplicar formato cuando debería ser lo contrario, pues cuando depuras te interesa ver la constitución completa del objeto que estás depurando. Dicho de otro modo, ¿por qué no usas `echo`?

Comment: La fecha se me esta imprimiendo de esta manera 2019-02-06 00:00:00, lo que quiero es que se imprima a si 2019-02-06

Comment: Prueba con `echo $empleados[6]->tareas[0]->fecha_termino->format('Y-m-d') ;`

Comment: perfecto, me funciona, pero tambien necesito hacerlo en javascript porque lo renderizo con vuej

Comment: ¿Con Javascript? Eso es ya otra cosa, aquí estamos hablando de Laravel y PHP. Para Javascript y Vue.js revisa aquí mismo, me parece que hay preguntas sobre el tema y si no encuentras plantea una pregunta para Javascript.

Comment: Voy a agregar una respuesta que refleja las buenas prácticas de Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La otra respuesta sirve si es PHP puro, sin embargo, no resuelve todos los problemas del OP y no sigue las buenas prácticas ni las convenciones de Laravel.

Para darle formato de forma «permanente» a un atributo que es una fecha, utilizamos la propiedad `$casts` en el modelo:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'fecha_termino' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

De esta forma, siempre que se solicite dicho atributo, tendrá dicho formato, no hay que llamar al método format cada vez.

```
echo $empleados[6]->tareas[0]->fecha_termino;
```

Comment: Excelente. Yo respondí desde PHP puro que es lo que manejo, no uso Laravel. Considero que, si funciona para el OP esta debería ser la respuesta marcada como aceptada.

Answer (score 2):

El objeto que muestras es una fecha, por tanto puedes aplicarle el método `format`.

Por ejemplo:

```
echo $empleados[6]->tareas[0]->fecha_termino->format('Y-m-d') ;
```

Ahí le indicas que formatee la fecha en:

- `Y` : año de 4 dígitos
- `m` : mes de dos dígitos
- `d` : día de dos dígitos

[En el Manual de PHP vienen indicados todos los formatos de fecha posibles](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) para objetos del tipo `datetime`.

> **NOTA:**
>
> Esta respuesta está basada en código PHP puro. Dado que estás en un
>   entorno del framework `Laravel`, quizá conviene aplicar formato de
>   acuerdo a los estándares de ese entorno para que tu código sea
>   coherente. No obstante dejo la respuesta, que puede servir a alguien
>   que esté usando PHP puro.